# Euler divergent series $(-1)^nn!$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, nt.number-theory

Consider the series:
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nn!$$
We know that if $p$ is prime, this series converges in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $s_p\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the sum of this series.

Also let
$$s_{\infty}=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+1}dx\in\mathbb{R}$$

In $\mathbb{R}$ the series is not convergent; but we are using the theory of divergent series.

My question is: What is the connection between numbers $s_p$?

I want the relationship type $\prod_{p}\left(|s_p|_p\right)^{(1-1/p^3)}=1$.

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: care to give a reason why you expect this kind of a relationship?

Comment: The series is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and therefore can be a formula which reflects the symmetry between the sum of this series in different completions $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\vert s_p\vert_p$ is zero for all $p<10000$ except $p=2$, $5$, $13$, $37$, and $463$ where it is $1/p$ making the product over all primes smaller than $5\cdot 10^{-7}$. Meanwhile $s_{\infty} = 0.596...$.

Comment: @Chris: is it a general fact ( that the sum is either 0 or $1/p$?

Comment: was the "thy" series intentional! MO is getting older by the day!

Comment: More elementary:  The terms in the series are all integers, so $|s_p|_p \le 1$ for finite $p$.  So if $|s_\infty|_\infty < 1$ as Chris says, then your product is certainly not $1$.

Comment: If I read the comments in http://oeis.org/A124779 correctly, $|s_p|_p$ is one for all $p< 150,000,000$ except the five given by Chris Wuthrich.

Comment: Yes, I agree that most likely the statement is false.